# Macbook Pro Retina 2012 Headphone Jack not Responding

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have a 2012 MBP Retina and it doesnt recorgnize my headphone jack.
I have tried to plugin several earphones but nothing happens.
also i tried resetting SMC and PRAM but still the same issue.
i am using Catalina.
inside the jack is pretty clean,
please help?

Comment: Boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting) and see if it works there.  If not, it's likely *physically* broken.  When you plug in your headphones, what do you see in *Sound Preferences → Output*?  (Click on Speaker icon in menu bar and select *Sound Preferences)

Comment: thanks man.. i think its physically broken